# Elasticsearch query with single letters

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a question to understand the retrieved results of an elasticsearch query.
F.e. I look for "london AND apartment AND in" and I get 8,500 results.
Then I look for "london AND apartment AND i" and I get the same result count but I'm expecting to find more results because I think there will be more words starting with an "i" instead "in"?

Answer (score 0):

Elastic search does not do partial match by default unless you have specified a specific analyzer or filter to it.

It can match only full words by default. Also if you use just the basic match query for querying then AND operator usually does not work.

You got to use **query_string** for using AND operator. In your case its just matching **AND** as separate word probably. and **i and in**  are probbaly not searched because those words are usually stop words and not stored in the index for search